# With Graph API call, one az ad app works and another app throughs Forbidden 403 error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Two apps registered in two different tenants with identical Microsoft graph permission.

[image]

All I am trying to use Powershell Invoke-RestMethod with Micorsoft Graph API. Same code, works for one but not the other one.

Any Idea why?

Not sure what to try. Access token gets created. App authentication message also prints on the screen (both cases)

[Click here for the picture of the full permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5a98.png)

Comment: Could you please help us to understand , what you are trying to achieve ? what you have tried and the complete error message .

Comment: Hi Vicky. I appreciate your help. With Imran's code, the Get Method works, but Put Method gives a Forbidden 403 error in one tenant (production), not on the other (dev). 

By the way, I am trying to create role-assignable groups using Graph api.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below.***

[image]

To resolve this issue, check whether you have granted ***admin consent*** like below.

[image]

After adding admin consent, use the below code to get token.

```perl
$tenantId = <tenantID>
$applicationId = <appID>
$secret= <secret>
$param = @{
        Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token? 
 api-version=2020-06-01";
        Method = 'Post';
        Body = @{ 
            grant_type = 'client_credentials'; 
            resource = 
      'https://graph.microsoft.com'; 
            client_id = $applicationId; 
            client_secret = $secret
        }
   }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod @param
$token = $result.access_token
```

[image]

You can change the **`Uri`** based on your requirement and run the below commands.

```json
$authHeader= @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $token)}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users  -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
```

***Result***:

[image]

Comment: Hi Imran. I appreciate your help. I have granted admin consent for both applications in both tenants. They are identical. With the token, I've also tried your method as well.


However, Get Method works, but Put Method gives a Forbidden 403 error in one tenant (production), not on the other (dev). 

By the way, I am trying to create role-assignable groups.

Comment: Also, when I am testing this in postman this is what I am getting:

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-11-15T04:14:05",
            "request-id": "245800b8-4e3f-4511-87e8-0e580dbfb1b0",
            "client-request-id": "245800b8-4e3f-4511-87e8-0e580dbfb1b0"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: what directory roles you have in your tenant?

Comment: I'm unsure what you meant, but I've found something related to the role. This one I found when I interpreted Graph Token:


  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "IdentityRiskyServicePrincipal.ReadWrite.All",
    "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD",
    "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup"
  ],

Comment: Check whether you have owner role in subscription level and if still the issue persists try to delete the application and try the same.

Comment: I have an Owner role, but the service principle has a contributor role at the Subscription level. I have also tried registering for another app with the same config but still, have the same result. :(

Comment: please include full screenshot of the API permission of application for which you are getting error to get clarity

Comment: I've added the picture in the description. I only was able to add it as a link.